# How to insert multiple variables inside c++ std::system()?

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to add multiple variables inside the std::system function. By using .c_str on the end it only accepts one variable.

```
system(("riverctl map normal " + modkey + " " + i + " set-focused-tags " + decimal).c_str);
```

Comment: My advice is to initialize your `std::string` first. Don't try to do this all in 1 single line of code.

Comment: You didn't actually specify what is your current problem.

Comment: You need `()` after `c_str`.

Comment: It's also unclear what types `modkey`, `i`, and `decimal` are. If they aren't `std::string`, then the result of adding them to a `const char*` is unlikely to be a `std::string`.

Comment: The issue here has nothing to do with `std::system`; it's about how to create a string from text snippets and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
"riverctl map normal " + modkey
```

calls `operator+` on two things: `"riverctl map normal "` and `modkey`. Which `operator+` this is depends on the types of the two operands of `+`.

You want it to call `operator+` which concatenates strings; if any of the two first operands is a string (`std::string`), the first `+` will do the right thing, and all the following `+` will do too (because the result of the first `+` would be `std::string`).

If `modkey` is an integer (any type of integer, including `char`), this `+` will do the wrong thing (unwanted pointer arithmetic). To fix, convert any of the first two operands to a string. If `modkey` is an integer, you have to use `std::to_string` on it anyway, so converting the first operand is not necessary. But for consistency (i.e. to stop worrying what would happen if you changed the format of your message), you might want to convert even the first one:

```
// minimal required change
system(("riverctl map normal " +
        std::to_string(modkey) + " " +
        std::to_string(i) + " set-focused-tags " + 
        std::to_string(decimal)).c_str());

// more robust code (C++14 and later)
system(("riverctl map normal "s +
        std::to_string(modkey) + " " +
        std::to_string(i) + " set-focused-tags " + 
        std::to_string(decimal)).c_str());

// more robust code (C++11)
system((std::string("riverctl map normal ") +
        std::to_string(modkey) + " " +
        std::to_string(i) + " set-focused-tags " + 
        std::to_string(decimal)).c_str());
```

---

If your command line is too complex, you might want to use a temporary stream for formatting; there are fewer surprises then:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << "riverctl map normal " << modkey << " " << i << " set-focused-tags " << decimal;
system(stream.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I ended up using stringstreams for easier understanding. Modkey is a string btw.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the format library:

**[C++20 format standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format)**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <format>

auto test(int modkey, int i, int decimal)
{
    auto cmd = std::format("riverctl map normal {} {}  set-focused-tags {}",
                           modkey, i, decimal);
    system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

or

**[{fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fmt/core.h>

auto test(int modkey, int i, int decimal)
{
    auto cmd = fmt::format("riverctl map normal {} {}  set-focused-tags {}",
                           modkey, i, decimal);
    system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case all variables declared in the system block are primitives (I guess that 'modkey' is already std::string) - you need to cast everything to std::string and call c_str as a function.

```
system(("riverctl map normal " + modkey + " " + std::to_string(i) + " set-focused-tags " + std::to_string(decimal)).c_str());
```